# Different SVN repository URLs for updating and committing?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have access to an SVN repository that allows public reading via one URL, and private committing via another. Is there any way to use the corresponding URLs locally? I don't want to save or enter credentials just for updating, but I'm happy to type them in when committing.

I'm using TortoiseSVN if it matters, in case there's a specific solution for that.

(Git can do this via having different "Push URLs" from the normal URL.)

Comment: I do not understand what "Is there any way to use the corresponding URLs locally" means. Could you please provide more information or reword the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion does not support this. Your working copy is linked to a single URL only.